# If I'm making a new programming language, should I compile to assembly or C?

Tags: c, assembly, programming-languages

I'm making a language that is based on a different mathematical model than is normally used.  If I use C, well, I'm not sure that I can because the model is so different compared to C.  But then if I use assembly code, it's not portable, is it?  Is there a generic assembly language that can be abstracted over all of the architectures possibly that I'm not aware about?  Or am I missing something?  I suppose that if C is Turing complete, then I should be able to compile to it if my language is Turing complete...  Is assembly more powerful than C?  If I wanted a compiled language, what are the advantages of compiling to assembly, and what are the advantages of compiling to C?

Comment: What are the problems you might have with the C model?  C is pretty in line with the way most popular hardware works already.  Have you looked into [LLVM](http://llvm.org)?

Comment: I would indeed have a look at LLVM. And currently your question is rather difficult to answer really. I'm not sure if it's a good fit for SO.

Comment: Another +1 for LLVM. There are even Haskell-to-LLVM compilers, for example. C is a bit dated these days as an intermediate language, so I wouldn't recommend it to start with (you'll end up with a GCC dependency pretty quickly!). For functional or other languages that have a very different feel to C, compiling straight down to LLVM might well be quicker to implement.

Comment: I'm trying to make a language that's very fast and powerful, so I figured that I should go with C or assembly if I wanted speed/power.

Comment: oh, and I neglected to mention, the language is going to be for concurrency, is compiling to C good for that?  If I want my language to be dynamic and strong, could I do that too?

Comment: C as a language doesn't have much in the way of concurrency, so you'll need to compile to C with some libraries as dependencies, and the concurrency performance of your language depends on the libraries and how you use them.

Comment: okay, concurrency libraries...how easily could I implement lisp-style macros if I'm compiling to C?

Comment: Macros would be resolved in the front end, before the question of code generation even arises. Note that there are a number of Lisp implementations which compile to C.

Comment: @Matt, LLVM is not a virtual machine like Java.  You get real machine code out the back.  It will be as fast as any C implementation you come up with, and probably a lot faster than an assembly implementation.  You're not likely to write all the optimizers yourself, right?

Comment: Ah, well in that case...everything shifts.  Thanks for bring that to my attention, Carl Norum!  Can you point me to any data on speed comparisons between C and LLVM and perhaps something else I've overlooked as well?

Comment: @Matt - clang/llvm are the system compiler on Mac OS X.  In my experience the speed of compilation of C code is WAY faster than GCC.  The output code is great for x86 and ARM (as you might expect, since those are popular architectures).  In my MIPS test, llvm was generating code about 10% slower than GCC for the same source in some tight image processing loops.  I'm sure they'll get there....

Comment: hmmmm, 10%.  But still, you say that it optimizes for me.

Comment: @Matt - that 10% was only for specific loops and only generating MIPS output.  x86 and ARM backends are much more mature.  And yes, LLVM has many optimizers.

Comment: On http://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html#gcc, it says that gcc supports more targets.  That means platforms such as x86 and the like, right?  What do they mean by targets?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17004/discussion-between-carl-norum-and-matt)

Answer (score 1):

I would say C. It will save you tons of time writing compilers for every platform when you can write one and let the C compiler do the dirty work for you. C has been used as intermediate language for a lot of higher-level languages with design different from C, such as C++.

Also, there are no assembly language that is cross platform without massive modification.

Comment: If you're going to go to C, go to LLVM instead - you get all of the benefits and a lot fewer hoops to jump through.

Comment: Carl Norum, I want speed, and the LLVM is not terribly fast, from what I understand

Comment: You want speed for what? You mean the run-time performance of your code? Or are you referring to the speed of compilation?

Comment: @Matt LLVM, when AOT-compiling with a well-chosen optimization pass order, can keep up with GCC with optimizations (though it's slightly slower in most benchmarks I've seen).

Comment: Bart, I was talking about the speed of a program's execution, but I would like to be able to compile as fast as possible too.

Comment: @Matt - what would make LLVM not fast?  The final output is regular machine code like any other compiler/assembler/linker combination would be.

Comment: I was under the impression that LLVM is tied to Java or something, but hmmmm.

Comment: Indeed, what you've stated about LLVM is a very attractive choice right now.  Make an answer so I could upvote it.